# fatal error: sstream: No such file or directory

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

I have included graphics.h header in my source file and i am trying to run an old C code in Code Blocks. I am using gcc version 4.8.1.I got the following error

```
fatal error: sstream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

`graphics.h` is including a c++ header `sstream`, you can't use it when compiling with a c compiler, switch your code to c++, that can be done by simply changing the file extension to `.cpp` for example or `.cc` and `gcc` will automatically use `g++` when compiling the file.

Comment: so i could not include graphics.h header in my c source file..?

Comment: No, you can write a c library and then a c++ and use the c library in the c program, but I don't know of any way of doing the opposite thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `stringstream`'s in C.In C++ they are.